# Why would getOrElse throw a NoSuchElementException (only when in Intellij debugger)?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

The "point" of invoking `getOrElse` is to allow for an element not to be in a Map - and to provide a defaul value in that case:

```
  /**  Returns the value associated with a key, or a default value if the key is not contained in the map.
   *   @param   key      the key.
   *   @param   default  a computation that yields a default value in case no binding for `key` is
   *                     found in the map.
   *   @tparam  B1       the result type of the default computation.
   *   @return  the value associated with `key` if it exists,
   *            otherwise the result of the `default` computation.
   *
   *   @usecase def getOrElse(key: A, default: => B): B
   *     @inheritdoc
   */
  def getOrElse[B1 >: B](key: A, default: => B1): B1 = get(key) match {
```

So then why would the `NoSuchElementException` be thrown on the following code:

```
  // nid = "LPKey-FToS"
  val nstateOld = state.activeNodes.getOrElse(nid, emptyNodeState)
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: LPKey-FToS
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at myClass$1.apply(MyClass.scala:162)
```

**Update**  Apparently this *only happens when debugging* in intellij after stepping through on a breakpoint. I am adding `Intellij-IDEA` tag to this question.

Comment: What is `BpmNState`? Looks to me like it's `apply` method is doing a lookup as well?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  That's a constructor of Case Class for BpmNState that just assigns primitives (no lookups happening).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  I removed the call to constructor from that line - and the error still occurs the same way. But what is interesting: only happens when stepping through code in Intellij debugger.

Comment: Can you post a complete reproduce so I can try it out?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  The code is confidential unfortunately. Setting up standalone demonstration may take time - will get back if/when I could do that.

Comment: You should be able to disable breaking on exceptions in the debugger. `getOrElse()` uses `get()`. Depending on the underlying implementation, `get()` may throw a `NoSuchElementException` as it does here. The `catch` clause turns this into a `None` which is then used in a case to choose the default value.